# jQuery on('hover') Event Replacement

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover, jquery-on

I'm looking to swap an img src on hover.  Typically I would use:

```
$('#img').hover(function() {
    $(this).attr('src', 'http://www.example.com/new-img.jpg');
});
```

However, I'm loading the content in via Ajax so normally I would use:

```
$('#main').on('hover', '#img', function() {
    $('#img').attr('src', 'http://www.example.com/new-img.jpg');
});
```

But I'm reading that on('hover', ...) was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in 1.9 ([jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/#additional-notes)), which is what I'm currently using.  Do anyone have any work arounds other than using:

```
$('#main').on('mouseenter', '#img', function() {
   $('#img').attr('src', 'http://www.example.com/new-img.jpg');
});

$('#main').on('mouseleave', '#img', function() {
   $('#img').attr('src', 'http://www.example.com/old-img.jpg');
});
```

Comment: what is the problem in using mouseenter and mouseleave ?

Comment: No problem with it, I'm just looking to see if anyone has a shorter/easier workaround.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you'll need to do it in two calls. But for added jQuery points, you can chain them:

```
$('#main').on('mouseenter', '#img', function() {
   $('#img').attr('src', 'http://www.example.com/new-img.jpg');
}).on('mouseleave', '#img', function() {
   $('#img').attr('src', 'http://www.example.com/old-img.jpg');
});
```

And as Benjamin comments below, you can optimise further (you get plain old Javascript points this time):

```
$('#main').on('mouseenter', '#img', function() {
   this.src = 'http://www.example.com/new-img.jpg';
}).on('mouseleave', '#img', function() {
   this.src = 'http://www.example.com/old-img.jpg';
});
```

Comment: chaining in this case make less sense then just passing multiple events into one `.on()` call.  As in Shaddow's answer.

Comment: @kmfk But that way doesn't support event delegation. "I'm loading the content in via Ajax"

Comment: Won't be able to use @Shaddow's since the content is loading via ajax...looks like I'll this is the way to go.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum And indeed `this.src`. Thanks: added.

Comment: ye, my old solution doesnt support event delagation

Comment: @roasted What's your point? This needs one handler for each type of event, not one for both of them.

Comment: @lonesomeday i was quite sure i didn't have posted this comment after seeing what shadow's answer was, sorry, i made a mistake here

Comment: @lonesomeday - I wasn't going to argue for the sake of arguing - because jquery does the work for you, this answer is still more concise. BUT! I really don't like the comment "doesn't support event delegation".  Of course it supports it with out chaining and its trivial to implement.  `Event Delegation` is not jquery specific.

Comment: @kmfk "Isn't designed for event delegation", then. You're right, it's not great wording on my part.

Answer (score 9):

You can apply multiple events and then check [`event.type`](http://api.jquery.com/event.type/) like this:

```
$('#main').on('mouseenter mouseleave', '#img', function(e) {
    $(this).attr('src', 'http://www.example.com/' + (e.type == 'moseenter' ? 'new-img.jpg' : 'old-img.jpg'));
});
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/AtFGy/)

You can also use `switch-case` or `if/else`:

```
$('#main').on('mouseenter mouseleave', '#img', function(e) {
    switch(e.type) {
        case 'mouseenter':
            $(this).attr('src', 'http://www.example.com/new-img.jpg');
            break;
        case 'mouseleave':
            $(this).attr('src', 'http://www.example.com/old-img.jpg');
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: best answer so far

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach that involves no JavaScript at all:

Instead of using an `<img>` with a `src` attribute use a div, give that div the same id (remember to give it the right width and height).

In your css, give that `div` a `background-image` something like:

```
#img{ 
    background-image: url('http://www.example.com/old-img.jpg');
}
```

On  `:hover`  change it

```
#img:hover{ 
    background-image: url('http://www.example.com/new-img.jpg');
}
```

([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5EADU/))

Comment: Well if I wanted to use CSS I'd probably just create a sprite and change the `background-position` for faster load times ;) ... But this was more of a curiosity.

Comment: @pennstate_fanboy Ah, ok, I thought you were not aware of the technique. This is preferable to the jQuery option by the way if you're just changing the image source. Especially with delegation.

Comment: True, like I said though, more of just a curiosity.  I have a few other events that are triggered on the same `hover` as well, so I figured I'd just throw the img src change in with it.

Comment: @pennstate_fanboy And I completely agree with you it's not a silver bullet. CSS pseudo selectors are only meant for representational behavior. If you have actual business logic that has to happen on hover they probably won't do. In those cases of presentation they're a lot faster and also easier imo.