# Passing local variables between chained event handlers in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a simple jQuery script that will alternate a source image of an `<img>` element on my website. I was wondering if it's possible to pass local variables from one event handler (for `mouseenter`) to the next, chained handler for the `mouseleave` event. This is my code:

```
            $("#homepage-media-slider li > img").on('mouseenter', function() {
                var ele = $(this);
                var eleSrc = $(this).attr('src');
                var overleafImage = $(this).attr('data-overleaf');
                ele.attr('src', overleafImage);
                ele.attr('data-overleaf', eleSrc);
            }).on('mouseleave', function() {
               ....
            });
```

I want to be able to use `ele`, `eleSrc` and `overleafImage` in the event handler for the `mouseleave` event handler in order to save myself having to write the same code again in this handler. Is it possible, if yes, how?

Comment: Why don't you define them in a global scope? Or alternatively you might specify a single callback for `mouseenter mouseleave`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First off, local variables are local to the function they are defined in so variables inside the event handler function for the one event are not available to another event handler function that is defined outside that function.

You can save yourself duplicating the code by combining your two event handlers into one event handling function where you use a common setup and then branch based on the event.

Here's a code example of that:

```
        // set up a single event handler for multiple events
        $("#homepage-media-slider li > img").on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
            // common code setup here
            var ele = $(this);
            var eleSrc = $(this).attr('src');

            // branch based on the event that occurred here
            if (e.type === "mouseenter") {
                // mouseenter code here
                var overleafImage = $(this).attr('data-overleaf');
                ele.attr('src', overleafImage);
                ele.attr('data-overleaf', eleSrc);
            } else {
                // mouse leave code here
            }
        });
```

Note, this is a much better way than moving the variables up to a higher scope and trying to share them because here, they are properly initialized for each event occurrence and would even work proerly if your event handler was serving multiple objects or if events arrived in an unusual order.

Comment: very good answer, also readers might check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/17301520/10980607

Answer (score 0):

Along the lines of @jfriend00 answer can leverage `hover()` which triggers for both events and combine the 2 handlers into one

```
$("#homepage-media-slider li > img").hover(function (e) {
    // which way are we going ?
    var isEnter = e.type === "mouseenter",
        ele = $(this),
        eleSrc = $(this).attr('src'),
        overleafImage = $(this).attr('data-overleaf');
    if (isEnter) {
        //mouseenter code
        ele.attr('src', overleafImage);
        ele.attr('data-overleaf', eleSrc);
    } else {
        // mouseleave code here
    }

});
```